# How to draw multi size using vispy?

Tags: vispy

I use following code to draw a point cloud in vispy

```
# init
view = vispy.sence.widgets.ViewBox()
vis = visuals.Markers()
view.add(vis)

# updata data
vis.set_data(data, 
    face_color = color,
    edge_color=color,
    size = 1
)

vispy.app.run
```

As you can see, I could set the fixed point size for whole data.
How can I set multi size in one data?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the size with a numpy array (one element for every marker point):

https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/932d6e499791a423822513549ebd825601345c85/vispy/visuals/markers.py#L517-L518

```
        size : float or array
            The symbol size in px.
```